# Way to execute JavaScript before a jquery submit call with no AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a JQuery UI modal that renders a partial MVC view if certain qualifiers exist. In my JavaScript, I only want the form to submit after the modal completes. This is what I have:

```
$('#btnSaveAndSend').click(function (e) {
        var result = _fieldsAreValid($('#validation').val() === "y");

        if (result) {

            if (showPrompt) {
                $('#divPrompt').dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 500,
                    height: 225,
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: "Modal",
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).load("/Home/SendEmail");
                    }
                });
            }
            $("#form").submit();               
        }
    });
```

Without AJAX, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Using a [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) for the parent's to check for its completion should do the trick. try replacing your `open` with this:

```
open: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).parent().promise().done(function () {
       $("#form").submit();
    });
}
```

Comment: I would assume that would occur after the .load line?

Comment: doesn't really matter, you're just adding a listener to the `done` event

Comment: The parent in this case is actually the open event, not detecting that the window has closed and the form has been submitted.